# jquery: correct drag position after css rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´ve several divs being draggable via jQuery like this

```
$( '#mystack div' ).draggable({ stack: "#mystack div",
start: function() { isDragging = true; },
stop:  function() { isDragging = false;}    
});
```

...works fine so far - now the problem is, that after I rotate a div via css-transform like

```
target.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
target.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
target.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
target.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
```

and then want to drag the image again - it kinda 'jumps' in its position when dragged again - meaning: its not staying at the mouse position (where the user started dragging the rotated div) but jumps a few pixel up or down or left after being rotated before?

Any chance or idea to correct that position after rotating?

Comment: Look into the `transform-origin` property.

Comment: hmmm, saying that i use transform origin like that:

target.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');

gives me a statement around which centerpoint I rotated/I will rotate... right? So what to do then? Correct the the position alongside the percentage I´ve rotated?

Comment: can you make a fiddle of this?